# ANSI_PADDING in a DACPAC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dacpac, dac, sqlpackage

When creating a DACPAC using SQLServer's sqlpackage.exe (from SQL Server 2014), so far I haven't seen ANSI_PADDING mentioned. And in some rare cases this is a problem as the database I'm working on seems to have a couple of fields where ANSI_PADDING is set to OFF.

Looking at the documentation on MSDN, this doesn't seem possible at all. We do need this exported as well as we're creating scripts to compare/develop/deploy our databases.

Does anyone here know if (and how) it's possible to include the ANSI_PADDING settings when creating a DACPAC? If it's not possible using sqlpackage, are there other ways that this setting on columns can be included in a dacpac export?

Answer (score 2):

The is_ansi_padded column property is completely ignored by the data-tier application framework (DacFX) that powers SqlPackage.exe.  If you're using an SSDT database project in Visual Studio, it's possible to use an alter column statement in a post-deployment script to set the ANSI_PADDING property.  This, though, is not possible using just SqlPackage.exe.